# Which tool to receive customer requirements

Tags: tfs, scrum, requirements, methodology

In my company we want to use Scrum lifecycle, we are using Team System 2010.
Team System is great to manage projects developpment and Scrum lifecycle.

However we are looking for a solution in order to take care of customers requirements.
A tool which give the ability to customer to send us their requests so we can plan it for next sprint.

Should i use TFS Web Access ? but which type of Work Item ?
I think TFS in general (not only Web Access) is for developpment team, not for customers ...

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: asks/specifications - you mean requirements?

Comment: @Gabriel Ščerbák : yes... i edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look on [UseResponse](http://www.useresponse.com) (PHP/MySQL, self-hosted). To be released in December, full sourcecode available on purchase, live demo available on [USWebStyle](http://support.uswebstyle.com) (UseResponse authors) website.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something very customer oriented, what about [uservoice](https://uservoice.com/) or [getsatisfaction](http://getsatisfaction.com/)? I also like [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) very much (best issue tracker in my opinion) but again, it may be too developer oriented.

Comment: Maybe solutions with SharePoint ?

Comment: @Yoann.B I don't have a very high opinion of SharePoint but, since I'm actually not an expert of it, I'll let someone with a deeper knowledge of MS products answer your question (BTW, do you want to host the solution?).

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of tools specialized on requirements management here: http://www.softdevtools.com/search.php?query=requirements+management&action=results

Answer (score 0):

We were always giving our clients access to the project backlog in [our scrum tool](http://www.bananascrum.com/). They could edit it there and we were always trying to get them to become Product Owners, usually with success. I see no reason why a client should not have access to the backlog the team is working off.